# How to query to find if all rows in one table match with a set of rows in another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

```
EXPERTISE
EID,SCODE
101,4001
101,4002
101,4003
101,4004
101,4005
101,4006
102,4002
102,4003
102,4006
103,4001
103,4006
103,4004
104,4004
104,4006
105,4002
105,4003
105,4004
105,4006
106,4001
106,4002
106,4003
106,4004
106,4005
106,4006
```

and

SPECIALTY

```
SCODE,SNAME
4001,Cardiology
4002,Pediatrics
4003,Oncology
4004,Psychiatry
4005,Opthamology
4006,Internal
```

How do I formulate a query that returns the EID(s) who specialize in EVERY specialty?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest method is aggregation and counting:

```
select e.eid
from expertise e
group by e.eid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from specialties);
```

This assumes that the tables do not have duplicates, which seems reasonable based on your sample data.  If there are duplicates, you can just use `count(distinct)` instead of `count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EID
FROM EXPERTISE
GROUP BY EID
HAVING COUNT(SCODE) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SPECIALTY)
```